# heroku build error: Treating warning as errors

Tags: heroku, build, netlify

Build error:
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.

My OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The error msg is self explanatory.
Here is how I fixed it:

If you are using Windows OS, then first install the `cross-env` as a dev dependency.(https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env).

Then update your build command in package.json as follows:

Ex: For a project using Create React App;
`"build": "cross-env CI=false react-scripts build"`

Done!